# PL SQL UPDATE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

```
create table item_stock
( itemcode        varchar2(11)   not null,
  name            varchar(27)    not null,
  des             varchar2(30),
  pcs             number(11),
  unit            varchar(7),
  qty             number(11),
  stkdate         date,
  constraint itemcodef_pk primary key(itemcode, name)
);



BEGIN
update table item_stock
set 'item_stock.itemcode' = 'item_stock.itemcode';
END;
```

```
Error 103 at line 2, column 14
Encountered the sysmbol "ITEM_STOCK" when expecting one of the following.
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this error.

Comment: `'item_stock.itemcode'` is not a valid column name

Comment: remove quotes around `'item_stock.itemcode'`

Comment: Bro i use this code in save button item_stock is block name save button

if i use   like this     BEGIN
update table item_stock
set 'itemcode' = 'itemcode';
END;

  & the error same

Comment: UPDATE item_stock SET itemcode = 'value';

Comment: UPDATE item_stock SET item_stock.itemcode = 'item_stock.itemcode';
commit_form; 

its compile fine but when press button it's give me the error

FRM-40735:WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-12899.

Comment: You're getting "value too large for column", given that you are trying to insert the string 'item_stock.itemcode' into a field that is only 11 characters long

Comment: Are you using Oracle Apex?

Comment: Why are you putting the literal value `'item_stock.itemcode'` into that 11-char column? Where is the value really supposed to be coming from - user input, another table, somewhere else? Or do you really want to set it to itself - which would be a bit pointless? It's not normally sensible to update (change) the value of a primary key anyway, particularly if there are foreign-key references; and having a composite PK looks strange too.

Comment: No I Using 10g forms Developer

Comment: There are no foreign key I want  want to set it to itself  update itself i pick that data using LOV.

Comment: If you need to update the field with a value from a LOV, you need `UPDATE item_stock SET itemcode = VALUE_FROM_YOUR_LOV`, being sure that your LOV can not contain values longer than 11 characters. You only need to understand the way to refer the value from your LOV and use it in the update statement

Comment: Bro can you give complete code that how to update value which i pick with LOV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one:

```
Update item_stock A
   Set A.itemcode = item_stock.itemcode;
```

Note:

The data type of the `item_stock.itemcode` must be same as `A.itemcode`.

Comment: UPDATE item_stock SET item_stock.itemcode = 'item_stock.itemcode';
commit_form; 

its compile fine but when press button it's give me the error

FRM-40735:WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-12899.

Comment: The error ORA-12899 : check the data type value of both updating columns, and you can pass the data within that range only .                    Exa :   itemcode   Varchar2(10);                                                                                                                                           item_stock.itemcode   Varchar2(10);                                                                                            item_stock.itemcode :='0123456789' ;

Comment: create or replace trigger item_hist_trigger
after insert on item_stock
for each row
declare
v_stkdate  date;
BEGIN
SELECT sysdate into v_stkdate
from dual;
insert into item_hist
values ( :new.itemcode
        ,:new.name
        ,:new.des
        ,:new.pcs
        ,:new.unit
        ,:new.qty
        ,v_stkdate
       );
END;